# Toggle a single table while hiding other tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I'd like to toggle a table when one of the link is clicked. And if I am going to click another link to toggle the other table, the previous table that has been toggled should hide. I have an href like this:

```
  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><?php echo 'Welcome, '.$name; ?></a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#" class="toggle-link">President</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="toggle-link">Vice President</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="toggle-link">Secretary</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="toggle-link">Treasurer</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
```

and i also have a data tables below that should be toggled:

```
<div class="candidates" style="display: none">
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>President Lists:</h3>
    </div>
<form align="center" method = "post" action="processvote.php">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive candidates">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Photo</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Partylist</th>
                <th>Position</th>                   
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <?php
                $query_get_users = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE position = 'President'");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_get_users)) {

                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $photo = $row['photo'];
                    $name = $row['name'];
                    $partylist = $row['partylist'];
                    $position = $row['position'];
                ?>
                <td><img src="<?php echo $upload_dir.$photo; ?>" height="40"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"> <?php echo $name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $partylist; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $position; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<br></br>
<td><center><input type="submit" name="vote" value="VOTE"></center></td>
</form>
</div>

<div class="candidates" style="display: none;">
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Vice President Lists:</h3>
    </div>
<form align="center" method = "post" action="processvote.php">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive candidates">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Photo</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Partylist</th>
                <th>Position</th>                   
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <?php
                $query_get_users = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE position = 'Vice President'");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_get_users)) {

                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $photo = $row['photo'];
                    $name = $row['name'];
                    $partylist = $row['partylist'];
                    $position = $row['position'];
                ?>
                <td><img src="<?php echo $upload_dir.$photo; ?>" height="40"></td>
                <td><input type="radio" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"> <?php echo $name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $partylist; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $position; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<br></br>
<td><center><input type="submit" name="vote" value="VOTE"></center></td>
</form>
</div>
```

For example, I'm going to click the link **President** it will toggle the table President. and if I'm going to click the **Vice President** link, the table for vice president should toggle and the President table should hide. How can I implement this? So far, I have tried to do a jquery below:

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {

        $(this).siblings().show();
        $(this).parent().siblings().each(function(index, element) {

            $(element).find('.candidates:visible').hide();
        })
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: can you add what you have tried so far?

Comment: @guradio sir, i edited my question with my jquery code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do these three changes in your code:-

1. Give your tables a class or and Id like :

`<div id="vicePresident" class="candidates" style="display: none;">
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Vice President Lists:</h3>
    </div>`

2. Add these new ids as a custom attribute **data-tableid** in your navigation:

   ```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="#" data-tableid="tabPresident" class="toggle-link">President</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" data-tableid="tabVicePresident" class="toggle-link">Vice President</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" data-tableid="tabSecretary" class="toggle-link">Secretary</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" data-tableid="tabTreasurer" class="toggle-link">Treasurer</a></li>
   </ul>
   ```
3. Javascript change , change the click handler to read this data-tableid attribute:

`$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {
          //1. Hide all candidate class elements
          $(".candidates").hide();

          //2. Show the candidate which is clicked based on the data-tableid
          var idOfTable = $(event.target).data("tableid");
          $('#'+idOfTable).show();
     })`

Comment: my bad. I'm the one that's wrong. this code works. thanks so much for your answer sir. it works fine now.